# Kuberenetes Ingress - infinite redirect loops

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to terminate ssl at ingress controller nlb level. But I'm getting infinite redirect loops.

If I remove the following code then the redirection stops. Note: I haven't updated the tls-secret yet. I'm using AWS Certificate so don't know the private key.

```
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Any idea why this redirect loop happens and how I can prevent it?

`ingress:`

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: httpd
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
```

`Ingress controller service:` 443 target port is set to http just to terminate ssl.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn-xxxx"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.3.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: why you adding tls at ingress level when you already adding certs in the nlb service? `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn-xxxx"`?